Cannot get GradlePropertiesModel (V2) for project 'GradleProject{path=':app'}' (android studio bug)
Multiple build operations failed.
    Cannot get GradlePropertiesModel (V2) for project 'GradleProject{path=':app'}'

i am facing this issue in Android Studio Koala | 2024.1.
on invalidate/Restart it's working fine. But after some changes in gradle it's showing same error again and again. i have to invalidate/cache restart to run my code.
